# Yii: AjaxLink and ajax loaded section`s ajaxlink have same id yt0

Tags: yii

i have table with ajax link`s

```
  <?php 
  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

  'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
  'id'=>'tasklist',
  'columns'=> array(
          array('header'=>'', 
                'type' => 'raw',
                'name'=>'complete',
                'value'=>'"<i class=\"type glyphicon glyphicon-".$data->type->class."\"></i>"',
                //'value'=>'$data->type->name',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'tdleft'),
                ),

          array('header'=>'Title', 
                'type' =>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::ajaxLink($data->title,array("task/show", "id"=>$data->id), array("replace"=>"#taskdesc"))', 
                ),

          array('header'=>'Project',
                'type' =>'raw',
                'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->project->title,array("#"), array("data-toggle"=>"tooltip", "data-placement"=>"top","title"=>$data->project->title))',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'tdpr'),
                ),
          )
  ));   
 ?>
```

And in same page , at right section have

```
<div id="taskdesc"></div>
```

So, when user click on "Title", in div rendered some view (via rederPartial in the Controller), here is my controller`s action

```
 public function actionShow($id)
 {

$this->renderPartial('_show',
    array('model'=>$this->loadModel($id)), false, true);
 }
```

in my `_show` view there are new ajaxLink and my problem is here, this ajaxlink NOT WORKing, because this one has same id attribute "yt0". if i add new id attribute, then i have just working link, not ajax. ajaxlink not working. There are conflict with ajaxlink with same id attributes

Please, how can i solve this problem.